# Error installing Python-SWIG under linux

Tags: python, centos7, quantlib, quantlib-swig

When installing Python-SWIG under linux, there is an error that it can't find `quantlib-config`. As per the readme, I put the `quantlib-config` in a directory on the path, i.e., `/home/idf/bin` as can be seen below.

I still get an error.

```
sudo make -C Python install
[sudo] password for idf: 
make: Entering directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make  install-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
/home/idf/anaconda2/bin/python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
sh: quantlib-config: command not found
sh: quantlib-config: command not found
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/QuantLib_Python-1.7-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/QuantLib_Python-1.7-py2.7.egg-info
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make: Leaving directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$ echo $PATH
/home/idf/anaconda2/bin:/bin:/home/idf/bin:/home/idf/anaconda2/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/idf/.local/bin

[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$ ls -la /home/idf/bin
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 idf idf 4096 Jan  2 21:49 .
drwx--x--- 29 idf idf 4096 Jan  3 18:29 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 idf idf  919 Jan  2 21:49 quantlib-config
[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$
```

**EDIT**

```
[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$ which quantlib-config 
~/bin/quantlib-config
[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$ sudo which quantlib-config 
[sudo] password for idf: 
which: no quantlib-config in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
[idf@node3 QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$
```

Comment: If you execute `which quantlib-config`, do you find the command? What if you execute `sudo which quantlib-config`?

Comment: That was the problem. I edited the file /etc/sudoers using visudo and update the line: Defaults    secure_path = "path_to_quantlib_config:etc"